# Algebraic multiplicity of the rotation matrix eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ and $D(\theta)=\pmatrix{\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\\ }$.

Let $\theta \notin \{0,\pi\}$. Determine the algebraic multiplicty of eigenvalues of $D(\theta)$.

I've calculated the eigenvalues: $\lambda=\cos\theta\pm i\sin\theta=e^{\pm i\theta}$. But I'm confused about the multiplicity of them.

My approach is; let $\lambda_1 = \cos\theta+ i\sin\theta=e^{i\theta}$ and $\lambda_2 = \cos\theta- i\sin\theta=e^{-i\theta}$. Since $\theta \notin \{0,\pi\}$ the cases, where $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$, are excluded so the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalues is 1. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.  It's a two dimensional matrix.  It can only have two eigenvalues total.  Since you found two different eigenvalues, that's all there are, and they must have multiplicity one each.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor Thank you!!

Comment: More generally, the matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}$$ has eigenvalues $a\pm bi.$ With $b=0$ it is $a$ with multiplicity $2.$